# .Net Core Context ServiceLifetime types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to understand what are the pros and cons of using the different types of lifetimes for DBContexts in .net core.

[image: ServiceLifetime enum]

I have a problem currently where if I make multiple calls I get back an error:

```
InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext.
```

I know I can use Transient ServiceLifeTime to solve this, but what are the negatives and what should I do instead? If this question is too abstract, please modify it accordingly.

*EDIT*:

It turns out, by injecting a scoped service through a constructor, it forces the service to become a singleton:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to use Invoke or InvokeAsync? I do not know how to not use a constructor.

Comment: how are you injecting your dbcontext? are you doing `services.AddDbContext<context>()`

Comment: @Bugbeeb services.AddDbContext<ManagementDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(VALUE_HERE).EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application will create a new instance of the db service per client request, meaning that, as long as the request exists, it will use the same instance of the db context within the request.

You can run into concurrency issues if you try to synchronously invoke a db context method before another call to the database has finished because the scoped instance of the context will block all access from other threads until the operation is complete. For this reason, you need to use async/await on your scoped service lifetime context or run everything synchronously (very slow). Transient lifetime creates a new instance of the service anytime it's called and therefore you won't run into concurrency issues because it's running on a single thread. Scoped services are considered an optimized way to use the dependency because you don't have to keep calling on the service provider for a new instance of the context within a single client request which slows down performance. Both scoped and transient will dispose of the instance when the request or method is completed.

If you don't like my answer, here are some good articles I found:

- https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/03/25/net-core-dependency-injection-lifetimes-explained/
- https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: I was going to ask for a more detailed response, but the article is exactly that, thank you so much, when I am allowed to, I will set your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Actually, I looked more into it, and it turns out that I was using the lifetimes properly, the issue comes from the fact that I put the services in the constructor, which turns them into singleton lifetime https://imgur.com/a/0WJFAS4 . It says there to use invoke, but I don't really understand how to use it, can you help with that?